# Refreshing data in a div with ajax

Tags: ajax, cordova

I'm developing a Phonegap based app which shows some data that is stored in a remote server. How can I make it refresh data every certain time in case an error happened and it didn't get the data the first time?

this is the list.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    
    var output = $('#vehiculosOutput');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.periodicosonofertas.com/mobile/conexVehiculos.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){
                var landmark = '<li>'+item.name + '<p></p>'
                + '<p><font style="white-space:normal; font-size: small" >'+item.descripcion+'</p>' + '<p>'+item.contacto+'</p>' + '<p>'+item.telefono+'</p>' + '<p>'+item.correo+'</p><p>'+status+'</p></li>';

                output.append(landmark);
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            output.text('Error');
            //setTimeout(func.updateStatus, 1000);
        }
    });
    
});
```

Comment: You mean to say you want to resend the request each time if there is an error in response?

Comment: Yes, something like that, for example if you initially didn't have internet connection, it's an error, and when you connect again it doesn't get the data even if I poll

Answer (score 4):

You can use **long polling** for this. In case if you haven't heard about it, [this](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) is a good place to start. 
If you need to resend the request only in error case, the following snippet would work.

```
(function poll(delay){
        setTimeout(function(){

          $.ajax({ 
                    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/time/",                         
                    success: function(data){
                            $('#requiredDivId').text(data.value);
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                        //Recursive **Poll**
                        poll(30000);
                    },                  
                    dataType: "json"
                });
      }, delay);
})(0);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I make it retry a connection, like if you didn't have internet at the beginning, make a request again when you reconnect, thanks in advance

Comment: @GilbertoRomero: The above code will work for the case you mentioned as well. If you didn't have internet at the beginning, `$.ajax` will call `error: function` which is a recursive call to poll. However you may not be able to identify the specific cause of error (it can be a network error, server error, etc).

Comment: @GilbertoRomero You've made 6 questions without accepting any answer. In case an answer solves your issue, you should reward the poster by accepting this answer as correct. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with specific feature you mentioned in your comment then there is a function named **network.isReachable**(You can find more details [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/0.9.6/phonegap_network_network.md.html)) in phonegap. You can put that function to check whether connection is on or not within settimeout function and if its true then you can run function to send data to server.

I hope it'll help you